# Received check and 1099-MISC in different years

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099-misc

When reporting on a cash basis for Schedule C: what if a check arrives late in a year, but the matching 1099-MISC was issued for the prior year?

In other words, what if a client issues the 1099-MISC for 2014, but the check arrives in March 2015.

Can I choose to report the income in the prior year?

If I choose to report the income in the year received, how can this be reported to avoid matching problems with the IRS?

Comment: How late? Did the client actually cut the check in the next year and issued 1099 for the previous?

Comment: @littleadv exactly.

Comment: Then you should ask them to issue a corrected 1099. Can you prove that that's what they did? Is the date on the check for the next year?